# Eloquent query to get all posts that have more than 0 views, but not exclude posts created_at past 24 hours?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have posts that have`views`field.

I want to query all posts and order them by `created_at`, however, I want to exclude the posts that are older than 24 hours that have 0 views.

If I do:

```
$posts = Post::where('views', '>', 0)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

I exclude posts from the last 24 hours that don't have views, how to update the above query, so where 'views' clause is only related to posts that are older than 24 hours?

Comment: do you want last 24hours post data with more than 0 views?

Comment: @DilipHirapara No, I need all posts from past 24hours + posts with more then 0 views from the rest of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use orWhere() call to do an or condition on a new where clause.

```
Post::where('views', '>', 0)
    ->orWhere('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDay())
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

If you have multiple where conditions, it could be preferable to do you wheres inside a where to avoid the [precedence](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-operator-precedence/) of the conditions to give you faulty logic.

Imagine adding extra logic only for a given team.

```
Post::where('team_id', 1)
    ->where('views', '>', 0)
    ->orWhere('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDay())
```

This will select a given team with views over 0 or something created within the last 24 hours. But often you want team_id in both conditions. Therefor wrapping it in another where clause is beneficial.

```
Post::where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('views', '>', 0)
    $query->orWhere('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDay())
});
```

Which will wrap you SQL conditions in parenthesis, which is way more sturdy and less error prone.

```
where (views >= 0 or created_at >= '2020-01-28 00:00:00')
```

Answer (score 2):

you can pass a function in where method like this

```
Post::where(function($q) {
   $q->where('views', '>', 0)
    ->orWhere('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDay());
 })
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Comment: You don't need any closure here, since it's only 2 conditions.

Comment: As added to my own answer, i think it is a more sturdy example of it and way less error prone. Since stackoverflow is copy paste driven, it is important to tell the reasons why and this is important to know :)

Comment: Thank you, I was missing the "orWhere" knowledge. I will know in future how to do this.

Comment: Thank VincentDecaux and mrhm. I will care about it.